# How to round a number in C?

Tags: c, rounding

I tried searching this up on Stack Overflow but couldn't find an answer.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
 

double y;
printf("Enter a number: ");
scanf("%lf", &y);
printf("Your number when rounded is: %.2lf", y); 
//If user inputs 5.05286, how can i round off this number so as to get the output as 5.00
//I want the output to be rounded as well as to be 2 decimal places like 10.6789 becomes 11.00


return 0;
}
```

I want to round a number, for example, if the number is `5.05286`, it should be rounded to `5.00`, and if it is `5.678901`, it will be rounded to `6.00` with `2`decimal places. The number `5.678901` is getting rounded to `5.05` but it should round to `5`. I am aware that I can use `floor()` and `ceil()`, but I don't think I will be able to round off the answer without conditional statements, which is not the scope of my `C` knowledge. I also tried to use the `round()` function but it doesn't round at all.

Comment: what about `floor(y*100+0.5)/100`, btw, isn't `5.05286` rounded to two decimal places just `5.05`? Just making the last two decimal places zero is not rounding to two decimal places. Your description would fit floor(y+0.5). You don't need condition if you realize that `if x is over 0.5` is the same as `x + 0.5 > 1`.

Comment: *I also tried to use the round() function but it doesn't round at all.* Not sure what you mean - did you just use something like `round(y);`? That won't work, but `y = round(y);` *will* work.

Comment: You should provide your attempt with `round`.

Comment: *"I also tried to use the round() function but it doesn't round at all."* - Then you're doing something wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to import `<math.h>` header :

```c
#include <math.h> //don't forget to import this !

double a;
a = round(5.05286); //will be rounded to 5.00
```

This function has analog definitions for every type, which means that you can pass the following types and it'll be rounded to the nearest for every one of them :

```c
double round(double a);
float roundf(float a);
long double roundl(long double a);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use any additional header:

```
    float x = 5.65286;
    x = (int)(x+0.5);
    printf("%.2f",x);
```

Comment: This has significant drawbacks for large numbers and does not work well for negative numbers.